# Display ETA and estimated money option for my "Ride there with Uber" button

Tags: uber-api

I have integrated a "Ride there with Uber" button to my app. I feel, it would be more convenient for the users, if i displayed the ETA and estimated pricing for the destination. How may I achieve this? I am following this guide as of now : https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk

It seems like I need, some kind of **product ID** to be able to achieve this. But how do i get it?

[image]

Made some progress, I got my self the product id, but it still doesn't work. Here is my current code:

[image]

Comment: Hello @Sanket Ray,i got solution

Comment: @KanhaiyaSharma Please post your solution :)

Comment: please check it out  @Sanket Ray

Answer (score 1):

Button will Deeplink into the Uber App and will simply open up the app. In order to see real-time fare estimates and pickup ETA information you will need to pass additional parameters to it. The Ride Request Button can accept optional parameters to pre-load some information into the ride request. You can see how to do it in the Uber [documentation](https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/button/ios#passing-parameters-to-the-button). Also this is explained [here](https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/blob/master/README.md) on the GitHub.

Comment: Could you please take a look at the question again...i edited with some changes. What am i missing?

Comment: You will need to make sure that product id you used is a valid product for the location you specified. I suggest using for testing purpose information available on uber documentation: https://developer.uber.com/docs/riders/ride-requests/tutorials/button/android#customize-button-parameters.  I also suggest you to see how test's are implemented - you may find some useful information there: https://github.com/uber/rides-ios-sdk/blob/master/source/UberRidesTests/RequestButtonTests.swift.

Comment: I somehow got to display the ETA. the only thing remaining is the price...After a lot of banging my head, i found out that, RidesClient.fetchRideRequestEstimate has a property called upfront fare, which may help. I am not sure, if thats the right approach? But, anyways, I always get "nil" as response from the method mentioned above :( Am I missing something?...Here's the github link : https://github.com/iamchingel/Ride-With-Uber

Comment: I have been able to get the pricing from RidesClient.fetchPriceEstimates. But I have no idea, how to integrate the price to the button :( Please help me out...I am a newbie and i have been stuck here for days now.

Comment: Sorry for late replay - what you need to do is to check do you have your : <key>UberClientID</key> and <key>UberServerToken</key> set up on the Info.plist. You can find this info on your developer dashboard. All other recomendations stay in place- so you will need to add productId, pickup and dropoff location and nickname's.

Comment: Yes, I have added both the ClientID and ServerToken, but it doesn't work....As of now, my Uber button displays only ETA of the vehicle, but not the price...Would you mind taking a look at my code? Here is the github link  : https://github.com/iamchingel/Ride-With-Uber

Comment: hope my answer above helps you

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution ||
**ViewController.swift**

```
var button = RideRequestButton()


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    let builder = RideParametersBuilder()
    let pickupLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.787654, longitude: -122.402760)
    let dropoffLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 37.775200, longitude: -122.417587)
    builder.pickupLocation  = pickupLocation
    builder.dropoffLocation = dropoffLocation
    builder.dropoffNickname = "Somewhere"
    builder.dropoffAddress  = "123 Fake St."

    var productID = ""
    let ridesClient = RidesClient()
    ridesClient.fetchProducts(pickupLocation: pickupLocation) { (product, response) in
        productID = product[1].productID!
        builder.productID = productID
    }

    ridesClient.fetchPriceEstimates(pickupLocation: pickupLocation, dropoffLocation: dropoffLocation) { (price, response) in
        print(price[0].estimate!)

        self.button.rideParameters = builder.build()
        self.button.loadRideInformation()
    }
    button.center = self.view.center
    self.view.addSubview(button)
}
```

Also, do make little change into UberRides->**RideRequestButton.swift**`

override public func setContent() {
        super.setContent()

```
    uberMetadataLabel.numberOfLines = 0
    uberMetadataLabel.sizeToFit()`
```

and

```
private func setMultilineAttributedString(title: String, subtitle: String = "", surge: Bool = false) {
    let metadataFont = UIFont(name: "HelveticaNeue-Regular", size: 10) ?? UIFont.systemFont(ofSize: 10)
```

and last one change width (+30) of uberMetadataLabel below like

override public func sizeThatFits(_ size: CGSize) -> CGSize

```
var width: CGFloat = 4*horizontalEdgePadding + imageLabelPadding + logoSize.width + titleSize.width+30
```

If any query please comment here

Comment: How did you generate a server token?

Answer (score 0):

The issue is kind of funny and I think uber should change there documentation. You need to **fetch products** and **price estimates** and then **loadRideInformation()**. Guess what! the default button width is smaller than required. *(Don't forget to add both the ClientID and ServerToken)*

```
        let pickupLocation = CLLocation(latitude:23.782221 , longitude:90.395263 )
        let dropoffLocation = CLLocation(latitude: 23.8116404, longitude: 90.4279034)

        let uberClient = RidesClient()
        let builder = RideParametersBuilder()
        let uberReqButton = RideRequestButton()
        uberReqButton.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: self.view.frame.width, height: uberReqButton.frame.height)
        self.uberview.addSubview(uberReqButton)
        SKActivityIndicator.show()

        uberClient.fetchProducts(pickupLocation: pickupLocation, completion: { (Products, _) in
            if (Products[0].productID != nil){
                uberClient.fetchPriceEstimates(pickupLocation: pickupLocation, dropoffLocation: dropoffLocation) { (priceEstimates, Response) in

                    SKActivityIndicator.dismiss()// used for loading animation, ignore if not not needed
                    builder.pickupLocation = pickupLocation
                    builder.pickupAddress = "pickup Address"
                    builder.pickupNickname = "pickup nick"
                    builder.dropoffLocation = dropoffLocation
                    builder.dropoffAddress = "drop Address"
                    builder.dropoffNickname = "drop nick"
                    builder.productID = Products[0].productID

                    uberReqButton.rideParameters = builder.build()

                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        uberReqButton.loadRideInformation()
                    }
                }
            }
        })
```